# Could someone provide me with an elegant visual proof of the Taylor Series expansion?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, alternative-proof

I'm looking for an elegant visual proof the Taylor Series Expansion. It could be a picture or an animation, whichever you think would work best. The proof doesn't necessarily have to be rigorous or actually include the expansion, but I'd really like it if you could make it intuitive.

Comment: not a proof but this: http://www.mathdemos.org/mathdemos/TaylorPolynomials/ has cool animations (the course on KA seems also pretty nice and visual: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/taylor-series-calc/v/visualizing-taylor-series-approximations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is no visual proof of taylor series or maybe very difficult,  but if you need to see what happens if you add more terms of any series of a function, for example $e^x$ function

$n=0$
 $$y=1$$
 $n=1$
$$y=1+x$$
$n=2$
$$y=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$$
and so on as shown in photo

[image]

Comment: I would say "of an *analytic* function".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That really helps you visualize what the Taylor Series is really doing.